# Scrollsnap JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm looking for someone proficient in Javascript. The site I'm using uses a javascript file to initialize the plugins and load settings and what not. So after reading some of
http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/

I decided to use it to snap to my divs(all with the class "slide")...
However placing this

```
    $(window).scrollsnap({
    snaps: '.slide',
    proximity: 100
});
```

in my js.js file accomplished nothing

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The code I used with that was this and it worked, give it a try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollsnap({
    snaps: '.slide',
    proximity: 100
    });
});
```

Not sure about $(window), where did you get that from?

Also, are you linking to the appropriate javascript files and to the jquery library? Make sure to put it at the end of your html like this:

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrollstop.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrollsnap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```